# register new users in openfire?

Tags: cocoa, ldap, xmpp, messaging, openfire

Is there anyway to register new users through an HTTP request in OpenFire.  I want users to be able to sign up for my messaging service from within an app written in cocoa.  Can this be done??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the web administration console's create-a-user page (`http://<openfire-server>:<port>/user-create.php`). It uses a simple HTTP GET form to create a new user. I imagine you could pull the submit URL and various required fields from the source of that page and build your own GET request from your Cocoa app.

Comment: I can not find any `http://<openfire-server>:<port>/user-create.php` instead there is `http://<openfire-server>:<port>/user-create.jsp`. when I tried building my GET request to it, it redirects me to the login page. that means it doesnot allow me to register user from outside.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to register a new user in Openfire is the UserService plugin. Just take a look at http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use the available user service plugin which is available in openfire admin console, choose the plugin tab, choose available plugin and click the green + button to install user service plugin; second, go to the server tab ->server setting page, and make sure you enable the user service plugin [image]

hope this can help the others~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

You can use rest API plugin in openfire

Go to plugin then go to available plugin then add rest API plugin then go to help page or

https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html

You'll get all the rest API to perform operation in openfire

Answer (score 0):

You can use in-band registration as specified in [XEP-77](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) to add accounts from the XMPP connection you're going to need.

Answer (score 0):

lookup about http-bind in your openfire server

http://localhost:9090/http-bind.jsp

I use strope js client lib work with my rails web project well, so I guess you can also use your own xmpp lib to realize it in your cocoa project